# What series are out there that represents a function?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis

I know that the Taylor series approximates a function by polynomials. What other series exists?
For example, I want to find a series representation for $\pi^x$. I can use Taylor series around a point. But what else?

Comment: Search for Laurent series (annulus), Fourier series (spectrum) and Dirichlet series (e.g. Riemann zeta), for example. Also Maclaurin series (a special form of Taylor)

Answer (score 0):

This is a super vague question, but I'll give a shot at answering it. Series representations are tied to convergence, and convergence is measured in some way- either by some norm or topology.

The Taylor Series is results from the convergence the Taylor polynomials uniformly on compact subsets.

What other series are possible? Under $L^2$ convergence on a finite interval, many types. For example, all of Fourier Analysis is understanding the properties of a function's fourier decomposition (either discrete for it's fourier series or continuous for its transform). There are other orthonormal bases of $L^2$, such as a wavelet basis, which have interesting properties.

What series can be used to represent $\pi^x$? We have
$$
\pi^x = \exp(x \log(\pi)) = \exp(c x)
$$ 
where $c$ is the constant $\log(\pi)$. This is just an exponential function. You can use the Taylor series.